# How to enable Hardware Encryption on Crucial MX500 SSD?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, self-encrypting-drive, tcg-opal

I have bought a 2 TB crucial MX500 SSD drive, and just installed it on a Windows 7 x64 machine, motherboard Gigabyte EP45-DS5 as a data drive.

Using the crucial Storage Executive software, I can see on the PSID Revert menu that the PSID revert cannot be triggered for the SSD drive and can read that the **encryption** is not supported on it. For the second drive (the system one, a standard HDD disk), I can read that that the **command** is not supported (not same words for the 2 disks).

and "The PSID recovery operation will be available when the disk meets all of the following conditions:
- Encryption is active on the disk. **<-- the problem**
- The disk does not contain any mounted partitions. **<-- OK**
- The disk is not connected to a RAID controller. **<-- OK**
- The disc is not a boot disc. **<-- OK**"

I have tried to create a partition, mount it, format it. Nothing helps me to have the encrypt mecanism active. I found nothing on the Crucial site (nor anywhere else) that helps me. Not a single word. The encryptions seems to be activated by default, with nothing to do to deal with it. I don't understand.

How can I know if the encrypt mecanism is active or not ?
And how can I activate it or be sure to permanently deactivate it ?

Before writing tons of datas on that disk...

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research and testing with a Crucial M500 I have, it appears that if the label includes a PSID then it is encrypted from the factory.  If you perform a PSID reset, then the encryption is permanently deactivated.  I have not contacted support regarding this, but after issuing the PSID reset, I now get an error stating that encryption is not supported on the drive.

Therefore, if you want to permanently deactivate the built-in encryption, I recommend issuing a PSID reset command from Crucial's Storage Executive tool.  Note that this will make all existing data on the drive unreadable and will appear as a clean drive after the process completes.

Comment: PSID revert doesn't "deactivate" encryption in any way. It resets the MEK (Media Encryption Key) and that effectively erases all data (instantly).

Comment: The drive can no longer be encrypted. I'd call that disabled, wouldn't you.  Note that I never mentioned that it would decrypt the drive, which you seem to think I was implying.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "can no longer be encrypted". By design, Opal SEDs are always encrypting written data. The only difference is whether MEK is protected by user password or not.