# Can encryption from Self-Encryption Drive (SED) be removed?

Tags: linux, encryption, sed

Can the actual encryption process be removed? Not the Authentication Key (AK) but the actual process embedded in the disk. Per my understanding it cannot be removed but I am confused with this post https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Introduction-to-Self-Encrypting-Drives-SED-557/#disable that states `Disable the current SED encryption`. So can encryption actually be removed?

Comment: What is your disk?

Comment: Crucial MX500 500GB, You mean some disk can be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that encryption on your disk can be disactivated.

I base this on the post
[How to enable Hardware Encryption on Crucial MX500 SSD?](https://superuser.com/questions/1462860/how-to-enable-hardware-encryption-on-crucial-mx500-ssd)

An answer on the post says to use Crucial's Storage Executive tool
and from it send the PSID reset command.
This will permanently disable encryption while erasing the disk.
(I take no responsibility for what else might happen.)

Comment: I don't think that *permanently* disables hardware encryption (although the M500 spec sheet doesn't list hardware encryption capabilities). Generally it resets the hardware key, rendering existing data unrecoverable and letting the drive be used without entering a specific encryption key.

Comment: @mpez0 don't confuse **M**500 with **MX**500. While the former (M500) is from 2013, the latter (MX500) is from 2018.